# Send Laravel verification email with a custom template using aws ses

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

What I am trying to do.

My goal is to send a custom blade template for the built-in Laravel email verification functionality. Right now in my `AuthServiceProvider` inside the `boot` function I call `VerifyEmail::toMailUsing` function and attempt to create an email based on the send_email function I already have. it takes a template name, email and params, finds the blade file, and inserts the params and sends the email with aws ses.

```php
VerifyEmail::toMailUsing(function ($notifiable, $url) {
    $params = [
        'first_name' => $notifiable->first_name,
        'verify_url' => $url
    ];

    $generate_email = new SendEmailController();
    $generate_email->send_email('verify', $notifiable->email, $params);
});
```

The issue:

The email gets sent successfully but throws an error:

[image]

I understand it must have to do with the toMailUsing, but just cant point my finger to it.

Expected outcome should be: no error :)

Comment: See the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/verification#verification-email-customization. Specifically, the part where it says "The closure should return an instance of Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage." If you want to use `VerifyEmail::toMailUsing` then you need to return a message, not send it yourself.

Comment: @jszobody it would be helpful if you could provide a solution or a hint, thank you

Comment: I did! You have a closure that is trying to send the email with your own controller. Don't do that. You should return an instance of MailMessage directly, just like the documentation example.

Comment: I think the main thing to understand here is that `VerifyEmail::toMailUsing` should not actually send an email. You don't send emails from a service provider. All you're doing here is customizing the verification email that Laravel will then send when appropriate. Make sense?

Comment: that makes sense, i guess my question is more of what would be the work around to not use the toMailUsing function, but instead something of my own

Comment: You can create your own new user verification process yourself from scratch, or use Laravel's the way it's designed. I don't think trying to do both is a good idea. That's where you start having issues like this.